# Como definir utilizar uma classe (center-block) na media-querie?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Estou utilizando o BS3 e gostaria de alinhar uma div ao centro quanto a resolução for maior que 1200px e a direita quando entre 992 e 1199px. No código utilizo a class center-block, como incluir essa classe apenas para a @media min-width: 1200px?

@media (min-width: 1200px) {

}

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
.alinhamento {
   float:right
   }
}

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia usar um pré-processador de CSS, como o LESS, para incluir a classe no seu media query, como **[neste exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18563604/)**, mas pode ser exagero dependendo do projeto.

Uma possibilidade de simplificar é usar uma classe ou id só, e atualizar esta classe em cada *media*, ou simplesmente copiar o conteúdo da classe original do BS3 no seu @media.

Muito provavelmente compensa você customizar manualmente no seu próprio `@media` somente os parâmetros que precisar.

Por exemplo:

```
@media screen and ( min-width: 992px ) and ( max-width: 1199px ) {
    #meubloco { position:relative; width:800px; margin: 0 auto }
}

@media screen and ( min-width: 1200px ) {
    #meubloco { float:right }
}
```

Se quiser testar os `@media` antes de definir as classes, uma maneira bem simples é essa:

```
#meubloco { width: 100%; height:20px; background-color: gray }
@media screen and ( min-width: 992px ) and ( max-width: 1199px ) {
    #meubloco { background-color: red }
}
@media screen and ( min-width: 1200px ) {
    #meubloco { background-color: green }
}
```

Assim você se assegura do `@media` estar funcionando antes mesmo de fazer o layout.